# Xcode constraints with images and text fields?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, constraints

I'm not too familiar with xcode and I'm trying to make an account creation form in the storyboard, however, I can't seem to figure out the constraints for the layout to work on iPhone 4, iPhone 5, etc.  I tried adding missing constraints but that doesn't help very much.  This is what it looks like running on different sizes.  I really want the text fields to fit wherever the form images are, but it doesn't always align.  Could anyone give me any tips or help?

[iPhone 6 Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFdK0.png)

[iPhone 4 Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teAl4.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple to learn, the flow is to align auto layout from the top most component, the best part is to try and align constraints and check parallelly in the Assistant editor's preview option(where you can check for all screen sizes).

-Align the textboxes and the buttons in such a way that they are in the centre of the screen.

-Try adding the first label's top margin and the "`centre horizontally in the container`" constraint, by linking it to the superview.

-Now add `width and height` constraints to that label.

-Add `vertical spacing` to all the textbox's(&button's) top component and bottom component.

-Select the "`First`" textbox and control select all the following textboxes and add "`leading`" constraint.

-Select the "`Last`" textbox and control select all the following textboxes and add "`trailing`" constraint.

-Select all the similar textboxes and give "`equal widths`" and "`equal heights`" constraints.

-Add `width and height` to the "`phonenumber`" textbook.

-`Center align` the "`create account`" button and provide `leading,trailing and height` constraints to it.

-`Center align the cancel button`, add `width, height and vertical spacing` to "`create account`" button and bottom space to superview constraints to it.

-Provide the bottom constraint of "`cancel`" button's priority to `500`, by double clicking on the bottom constraint blue line.

For further reference check the [sampleproject](https://github.com/githubofrajesh/AutoLayoutTutorial) that I've created. Please do try this and let me know if you face any difficulties.

P.S. You will know while looking at the UI, that this button's `width & height` must be similar to that of the next button, there you must add `Equal widths` & `Equal heights` constraint and you'll also see that all these textfield's should have a same x value(starting point), there you should select all those textfield's and add `leading` constraint to it, similarly for `trailing` constraint.

It's literally how you would understand the positions of the UI Components.

Answer (score 0):

download main.storyboard and set your design:

https://github.com/BhadreshKathiriya/AutoLayoutSignin

[image]
[image]

you are set two difference text field space:
[image]